# Finding all specific relations based on another pivot relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I know the title of my question is really weird! I hope I can clarify it with explanations. I have three models, Book, Auther, and AutherType. My tables structure :

table books:

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | book1 |
| 2 | book2 |

table authors:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob |
| 2 | Sara |

table author_types:

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | writer |
| 2 | translator |

Each Book can have multiple Authors with a type. The pivot table of this relationship is something like that:

| book_id | author_id | author_type_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |

Also, I have authors(general relation) and writers(partial relation) relationship in my Book model:

```
public function authors()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Author', 'author_book', 'book_id')->withPivot('author_type_id');
}

public function writers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Author', 'author_book', 'book_id')
        ->wherHas('authorType', function($q){
            $q->where('title', 'writer');
        })
        ->withPivot('author_type_id');
}
```

My question is that, how can I fetch all specific type of a book? For example, all writers of a book. In this case, the writer of the book1 is Bob. But my writers relation cannot satisfy this. The output of $book->writers for the book1 contains Bob and Sara. Because Sara has writer role for another book!

Answer (score 3):

While there is no ability to write queries on complex pivots (belongsToMany relations), we have two choices:

- First(which is the simplest one): get the writer type id and pass it through the relation, like:

```
public function writers()
{
    $writer_id = AuthorType::where('title', 'writer')->first()->id;
    return $this->authors()->wherePivot('author_type_id', $writer_id);
}
```

- Second (The heavy choice), write a new method in `Author` model that gives the author types for a specific book and then in `Book` model filter authors according there types for this book:

in `Author.php`:

```
public function authorTypes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\AuthorType', 'author_book');
}

public function authorTypesForBook($book_id){
    return $this->authorTypes()->wherePivot('book_id', '=' , $book_id);
}
```

and in `Book.php`:

```
public function writers()
{
    $authors = $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Author', 'author_book')->withPivot('author_type_id')->get();
    $book_id = $this->id;
    
    return $authors->filter(function ($item) use ($book_id){
        return $item->authorTypesForBook($book_id)->get()->contains(function($value){
            return $value->title == 'writer';
        });
    });
}
```

Hope this would help.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Regarding your first method, I was worried about the number of queries in the lazy loading. But I tested and only one query was added to the total number of queries. It's really helpful. Also for another use-case, I added a straight hasMany relationship to Author_book. That way I can  create my query with "whereHas" statement